# Python - Beautiful Soup - Retrieving Table Data

Tags: python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is my first question in StackOverflow and I would really appreciate your help! I am trying to scrape table data and convert into a csv file using python 2.7 and R from the NUFORC from this page: http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxl.html. I've seen dozens of tutorials and tried to follow along but none of them worked for this instance. I checked at the beautifulsoup documentation but i didnt find sth to pick up the trail. It appears that even the read clipboard command is not working (?)

The most promising approach is below. This is as far as I could go as I could not replicate the instructor's notes on this page.

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= "http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxl.html"

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup ("http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxl.html")

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        print (data.text)
```

While at least I can print the data now, I do not know how to proceed into extracting the data into a more useful .csv file.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) you can write the data directly to a csv file in your nested for loop.  For each row value in the row you would store it in an array then write the array to the row using write_row. Make sure to initialize the array to being empty for each row or you may end up adding  to the previous array over and over again.

Comment: Great, thank you I will check on that command and will update! I was hoping to save the web table data into a dataframe in python prior to .csv out. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: You can use [Panda dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), or if you want to go simpler you can do an array of arrays. 
`row_list = list() \n
for row in table \n
columns = list() \n
for item in row \n\t    columns.append(item) \n
row_list.append(columns)`